# Why does fixing the network input size reduce the model's file size

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've a model, whose inputs during training are variable in size, for generalisation.

In order to quantise, I have to fix the input size, so I just recreate the model with fixed input sizes, and copy across all the weights and biases, then save the model.
For some reason though, the model size gets roughly quartered. 
Note this is before quantisation or anything else, and parameters remain the same.

Two model summaries are below:

Model 1 = 4.6MB

```
old_model.summary(line_length=110)


  ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                        Output Shape            Param #      Connected to                         
==============================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)                (None, None, None, 4)   0                                                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_1 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 4)   0            input_1[0][0]                        
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 32)  1184         gaussian_noise_1[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 32)  128          conv2d_1[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_2 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 32)  0            batch_normalization_1[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 32)  9248         gaussian_noise_2[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 32)  128          conv2d_2[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_3 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 32)  0            batch_normalization_2[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  18496        gaussian_noise_3[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_3[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_4 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_3[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  36928        gaussian_noise_4[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_4[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_5 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_4[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)      (None, None, None, 64)  0            gaussian_noise_5[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)         (None, None, None, 96)  0            up_sampling2d_1[0][0]                
                                                                         batch_normalization_1[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_6 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 96)  0            concatenate_1[0][0]                  
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  55360        gaussian_noise_6[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_5[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_7 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_5[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  36928        gaussian_noise_7[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_6[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_8 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_6[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  36928        gaussian_noise_8[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_7[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_9 (GaussianNoise)    (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_7[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  36928        gaussian_noise_9[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_8[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_10 (GaussianNoise)   (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_8[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)                   (None, None, None, 64)  36928        gaussian_noise_10[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNormali (None, None, None, 64)  256          conv2d_9[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_11 (GaussianNoise)   (None, None, None, 64)  0            batch_normalization_9[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)      (None, None, None, 64)  0            gaussian_noise_11[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)                (None, None, None, 3)   0                                                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)         (None, None, None, 67)  0            up_sampling2d_2[0][0]                
                                                                         input_2[0][0]                        
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_12 (GaussianNoise)   (None, None, None, 67)  0            concatenate_2[0][0]                  
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)                  (None, None, None, 67)  40468        gaussian_noise_12[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNormal (None, None, None, 67)  268          conv2d_10[0][0]                      
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_13 (GaussianNoise)   (None, None, None, 67)  0            batch_normalization_10[0][0]         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)                  (None, None, None, 67)  40468        gaussian_noise_13[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNormal (None, None, None, 67)  268          conv2d_11[0][0]                      
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_14 (GaussianNoise)   (None, None, None, 67)  0            batch_normalization_11[0][0]         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)                  (None, None, None, 32)  19328        gaussian_noise_14[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNormal (None, None, None, 32)  128          conv2d_12[0][0]                      
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_15 (GaussianNoise)   (None, None, None, 32)  0            batch_normalization_12[0][0]         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)                  (None, None, None, 3)   867          gaussian_noise_15[0][0]              
==============================================================================================================
Total params: 372,771
Trainable params: 371,415
Non-trainable params: 1,356
```

Model 2 = 1.6MB

```
model.summary(line_length=110)
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                        Output Shape            Param #      Connected to                         
==============================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)                (None, 368, 256, 4)     0                                                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_1 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 368, 256, 4)     0            input_1[0][0]                        
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                   (None, 368, 256, 32)    1184         gaussian_noise_1[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNormali (None, 368, 256, 32)    128          conv2d_1[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_2 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 368, 256, 32)    0            batch_normalization_1[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)                   (None, 184, 128, 32)    9248         gaussian_noise_2[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNormali (None, 184, 128, 32)    128          conv2d_2[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_3 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 184, 128, 32)    0            batch_normalization_2[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                   (None, 184, 128, 64)    18496        gaussian_noise_3[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNormali (None, 184, 128, 64)    256          conv2d_3[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_4 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 184, 128, 64)    0            batch_normalization_3[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)                   (None, 184, 128, 64)    36928        gaussian_noise_4[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNormali (None, 184, 128, 64)    256          conv2d_4[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_5 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 184, 128, 64)    0            batch_normalization_4[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)      (None, 368, 256, 64)    0            gaussian_noise_5[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)         (None, 368, 256, 96)    0            up_sampling2d_1[0][0]                
                                                                         batch_normalization_1[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_6 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 368, 256, 96)    0            concatenate_1[0][0]                  
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)                   (None, 368, 256, 64)    55360        gaussian_noise_6[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNormali (None, 368, 256, 64)    256          conv2d_5[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_7 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 368, 256, 64)    0            batch_normalization_5[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)                   (None, 368, 256, 64)    36928        gaussian_noise_7[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNormali (None, 368, 256, 64)    256          conv2d_6[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_8 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 368, 256, 64)    0            batch_normalization_6[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)                   (None, 368, 256, 64)    36928        gaussian_noise_8[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNormali (None, 368, 256, 64)    256          conv2d_7[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_9 (GaussianNoise)    (None, 368, 256, 64)    0            batch_normalization_7[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)                   (None, 368, 256, 64)    36928        gaussian_noise_9[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNormali (None, 368, 256, 64)    256          conv2d_8[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_10 (GaussianNoise)   (None, 368, 256, 64)    0            batch_normalization_8[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)                   (None, 368, 256, 64)    36928        gaussian_noise_10[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNormali (None, 368, 256, 64)    256          conv2d_9[0][0]                       
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_11 (GaussianNoise)   (None, 368, 256, 64)    0            batch_normalization_9[0][0]          
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)      (None, 736, 512, 64)    0            gaussian_noise_11[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)                (None, 736, 512, 3)     0                                                 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)         (None, 736, 512, 67)    0            up_sampling2d_2[0][0]                
                                                                         input_2[0][0]                        
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_12 (GaussianNoise)   (None, 736, 512, 67)    0            concatenate_2[0][0]                  
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)                  (None, 736, 512, 67)    40468        gaussian_noise_12[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNormal (None, 736, 512, 67)    268          conv2d_10[0][0]                      
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_13 (GaussianNoise)   (None, 736, 512, 67)    0            batch_normalization_10[0][0]         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)                  (None, 736, 512, 67)    40468        gaussian_noise_13[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNormal (None, 736, 512, 67)    268          conv2d_11[0][0]                      
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_14 (GaussianNoise)   (None, 736, 512, 67)    0            batch_normalization_11[0][0]         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)                  (None, 736, 512, 32)    19328        gaussian_noise_14[0][0]              
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNormal (None, 736, 512, 32)    128          conv2d_12[0][0]                      
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_15 (GaussianNoise)   (None, 736, 512, 32)    0            batch_normalization_12[0][0]         
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)                  (None, 736, 512, 3)     867          gaussian_noise_15[0][0]              
==============================================================================================================
Total params: 372,771
Trainable params: 371,415
Non-trainable params: 1,356
___________________________
```

Comment: 372771 parameters translate to around 1.4MB, so I guess Model 2 has a much smaller graph. Maybe have a look at the two graphs in tensorboard?

Comment: Checked the grapsh and they're the same. Could it maybe be due to the fact that I haven't run any training on the new model? Does that sort of information get stored in a models save file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FCOS I think the difference is due to the fact that you haven't trained one model whereas the other model was trained.

When you save a trained model, it saves

1. model architecture,
2. weights & biases, and
3. optimizer's configuration

However, when you save a model that was not trained, it will not have optimizer's configuration.

To test the size difference, I created simple model with and without input size and found out that both the models have exactly same size as the number of parameters are same for both the models. Please check the `model1` and `model2` below.

### Here is model1

```
import tensorflow as tf

model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',input_shape=(None, None, 784,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model1.save('mymodel1.h5',overwrite=True,include_optimizer=True)
model1.summary()

Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 128)   100480    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 256)   33024     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 512)   131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 256)   131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 128)   32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 64)    8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)             (None, None, None, 10)    650       
=================================================================
Total params: 438,218
Trainable params: 438,218
Non-trainable params: 0
```

### Here is model2

```
model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',input_shape=(300, 300, 784,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model2.save('mymodel2.h5',overwrite=True,include_optimizer=True)
model2.summary()

Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 128)     100480    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 256)     33024     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_29 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 512)     131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 256)     131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 128)     32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 64)      8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 300, 300, 10)      650       
=================================================================
Total params: 438,218
Trainable params: 438,218
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Size of mode#1 and model#2 is same (1.7 MB).

Please let us know if you have any comments. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!
I didn't realize just how big the optimizer configuration data would be....